# Another word/phrase for precipitation?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there some word that I could use in place of precipitation when I don't know if it's raining, snowing, or hailing outside? Saying "there is probably precipitation right now" (in place of something more certain about the state of the precipitation like "I think it's raining right now") sounds stiff.

For instance, if I walk into a building while it's raining or snowing and ten minutes later someone asks about the weather (which is liable to change, especially during early winter), what could I say?

Comment: What's wrong with looking out of the window?

Comment: Sometimes I am in rooms are in the center of buildings or underground and don't have windows to the outside...

Comment: But wouldn't the temperature be a guideline? Below zero, it's likely to be snow; if it's the summer then it has to be rain. And if you find yourself on a floor without windows how could you tell there is any "precipitation"? I don't think you will find an answer to your question, the word, precipitation covers all the bases. It is quite formal, admittedly, but it's well known too.

Comment: My scenario typically goes like this: I walk in when it's still raining/snowing/sleeting/etc. out, and about ten minutes later someone is about to go outside and asks about the weather. Around early winter or early spring, it's hard to tell if it's snowing or raining. Thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: Add that comment to your question. It makes it much easier for users to understand your problem! :)

Comment: "Bad weather" is largely though not exactly synonymous with "weather involving some form of precipitation", and sounds less ridiculous.

Comment: Jocelyn, monitoring weather conditions, however, is always a good idea, but, if any, you can ask "Do I have better take an umbrella?"

Comment: In my humble opinion, there is really only one good response to that question, which is, "Well, it was raining (snowing, or whatever) when I came in ten minutes ago."

Comment: How about a simple "Wet!".

Comment: *"I had better bring an umbrella in any case"* or *"Had I better bring an umbrella?"* is, I think, what Carlo_R wanted to say.

Comment: How about *It's doing **something** out there!* The *doing* suggests activity (probably precipitation rather than wind) and the vagueness gives you room for the intermediate (which we often call *sleet*).

Comment: Or maybe we should latch onto the latest JamesBondian neologism - *Look out for the **skyfall***!

Comment: @Mari-L, yes, I used the 'do' support in honour to the English Language, do, do, do!

Comment: @ Carlo_R: You weren't honouring any form of English _I_ 've ever encountered. NOAD states: "In the verb phrase 'had better [+ second verb phrase]', the word 'had' acts like an auxiliary verb." To the extent that it doesn't accept do-support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just say "wet". This tends to be accepted in the English language quite happily, even when snowing as it still contains moisture.

Alternatively you could say "bad" which is often associated with wet weather.

Answer (score 0):

Meteorologists often use the term *precipitation* when predicting weather conditions in the future.
 From the [Edmonton Journal:](http://www.edmontonjournal.com/Fall+weather+bring+more+precipitation+than+usual/8816843/story.html)

> But get ready to don your warm, waterproof gear come September,
>   October and November when southern and central Alberta may see
>   significantly **more precipitation** than usual.
>
> “In November, it’s most likely not going to be rain,” Kulak said [a warning preparedness meteorologist for Environment Canada.]

In November it might not rain in Edmonton, but the weather expert cannot know for certain; he is merely speculating. If it became cold enough there could be sleet; or hail; or even snow.

On the UK Met Office site I found this [definition](http://www.metoffice.gov.uk/learning/rain/what-is-precipitation) of precipitation:

> **What is precipitation?**
>
> The definition of precipitation is any form of water - liquid or solid
>   - falling from the sky. It includes rain, sleet, snow, hail and drizzle plus a few less common occurrences such as ice pellets,
>   diamond dust and freezing rain.

Thus the word precipitation is best left to the meteorologists when they are making short or long term weather forecasts.

In the OP's case, the expression precipitation has been used incorrectly.

> "there is probably precipitation right now"

If the OP insisted on using the term then she ought to say **`It was precipitating when I arrived at work.`** This however, sounds stilted and is too vague to be of any real help. The person asking for information is left none the wiser. A far more natural, and *more accurate* description, as suggested by @John M. Landsberg in the comment section, would be to say

> It was raining/snowing/hailing when I arrived ten minutes ago

thereby leaving the asker; the task and responsibility of checking the weather conditions for him or herself.